# EF: How to execute a SQL-query with multiple joins?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Im working with Entity Framework version 6.1.3 and I want to execute a SQL-query
which gathers information from multiple tables like this:

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<SomeType>("SELECT SUM(d.PurchaseValue) AS 'Total', div.Name, l.Name " +
                                                  "FROM Device AS d " +
                                                  "RIGHT JOIN Location AS l " +
                                                  "ON d.LOCATION_ID = l.ID " +
                                                  "RIGHT JOIN Division AS div " +
                                                  "ON d.DIVISION_ID = div.ID " +
                                                  "GROUP BY div.Name, l.Name " +
                                                  "ORDER BY l.Name");
```

My question is, what should be the the type in SqlQuery<>? Or what is the proper way to execute a query like this and get a result out of it?

Comment: Any type with properties with the same names and matching types as columns in result set (Total, Name etc).

Comment: *wwhat is the proper way to execute a query like this* you should use linq

Comment: Doesn't int work?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman, well the query itself does work and it return many records since I use a group by statement. I just don't know how my SomeType class should look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `SomeType` can be any type that has properties which match the names of the columns returned from the query.

For example, your query returns columns:
**Total  |  Name**

Therefore, your return type (class) can be similar to below...

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Your query will be

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<List<SomeType>>(...);
```

Comment: Hi, will the Sample class be like that even with the GROUP BY clause in my query?

Comment: Sample class should contain properties that should match the column Name returned by your Query. It does not relate to GROUP BY

Comment: But this query returns many records, how can it fit in this model?

Comment: Columns name should match with properties name. I made change to post. so your query return a list of `Sample`

Comment: The "List" part of the query call is unnecessary since SqlQuery() already returns an IEnumerable of whatever type is in the angle brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen checked the [Data Development Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) for ways to do this?

Note '*Entity Framework allows you to query using LINQ with your entity classes. However, there may be times that you want to run queries using raw SQL directly against the database.*'

So if you can, use LINQ. Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx) to start.